# VS code python interactive window autocomplete: no suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am using the interactive windows for python in vs code. I found that suggestion can only be triggered by ".". ctrl+space does not work and when in assignment, it does not work either.
[triggered by "."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJPqx.png), [ctrl+space does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsX5s.png) [in assignment, it does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgG4c.png). Is there any setting I should add?